# Подскажите, как работает передача табличного параметра в процедуру из DataTable?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Подскажите, как работает передача табличного параметра в процедуру из `DataTable`?

Меня интересует:

### 1. Производительность

Будет ли это быстрее чем выполнение одиночных инструкций?

Например, в `DataTable` есть 1000 значений и их нужно вставить.

В одном случае я могу сделать 1000 инструкций `INSERT` из кода, а в другом послать этот `DataTable` целиком в процедуру.

### 2. Ограничение

Есть ли какие-то ограничение на размер передаваемого табличного аргумента?

Например, `INSERT INTO VALUES` может за раз вставлять только 1000.

### 3. Как происходит наполнение Табличной переменной?

На сервере создается эта переменная и она заполняется одичными инструкциями `INSERT INTO` из моей `DataTable` или что-то более интересное, например делает `INSERT INTO VALUES` по 1000 записей?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**По пункту 1**: При вставке одиночными инструкциями `INSERT`, по-видимому, лучшее, что можно сделать со стороны .Net для ускорения вставки - это соответствующий запрос параметризовать и подготовить (`cmd.Prepare()` перед входом в цикл в нижеследующем примере):

```cs
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into [Table] (ID, Name) values (@id, @name)";
    var p = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
    var p2 = new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

    cmd.Prepare();

    for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
    {
        p.Value = i;
        p2.Value = $"Name {i}";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

В этом случае, благодаря параметризации, парсинг и компиляция запроса произойдут один раз - при первом вызове `ExecuteNonQuery()`, а благодаря подготовке и сам текст запроса будет передан однократно. Повторно будет передаваться уже его *handle* (полученный при первом вызове), что может быть особенно выгодно, если текст запроса длинный.

Однако если строк много, то даже с параметризацией и подготовкой будут ощутимы издержки на организацию вызова, т.к. при каждом вызове (для каждой передаваемой строки данных) передаются не только полезные данные, но и вспомогательные (метаданные - такие, как, например, имена параметров и их типы). И результат (даже если это - всего лишь код успешного завершения) возвращается также для каждой строки.

В случае же передачи вставляемых данных через табличную переменную

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
    dt.Rows.Add(i, $"Name {i}");

using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = @"insert into [Table] (ID, Name) select ID, Name from @data";

    var p = new SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.Structured);
    p.TypeName = "dbo.TableType";
    p.Value = dt;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

метаданные, описывающие содержимое табличного параметра, передаются не для каждой строки, а один раз для всех строк табличной переменной. И результат возвращается тоже один, для всех строк сразу. Что даёт выигрыш тем больший, чем больше вставляется строк.

При таком подходе, однако, можно ожидать некоторых потерь в производительности на "перекладывании" данных (ведь данные вставляются в целевую таблицу из табличной переменной, а не напрямую, как в случае с одиночными `INSERT`).

Поэтому - да, вставка данных через табличную переменную будет быстрее, чем вставка одиночными `INSERT`, но, вероятнее всего, лишь после некоторого определенного количества строк.

Моделированием это подтверждается. Для приведенных примеров,

вставка 5 строк:

```
M1: 132 msec
M2: 19 msec
M3: 6 msec
M4: 34 msec
```

вставка 10'000 строк:

```
M1: 13614 msec
M2: 7555 msec
M3: 5020 msec
M4: 115 msec
```

где M1, M2, M3 и M4 - различные методы:

- M1 - одиночные вставки, не параметризованный запрос (вставка
  литералов)
- M2 - одиночные вставки, запрос параметризованный, но не
  подготовленный
- M3 - одиночные вставки, запрос параметризованный и подготовленный
- M4 - вставка из табличной переменной

**По пункту 2**: Табличная переменная может содержать от 1 до 1024 столбцов. Число строк произвольное и не ограничивается.

**По пункту 3**: Табличный параметр уходит на сервер сериализованным в TDS поток. На стороне сервера происходит его десериализация.

Анализ профайлером на стороне SqlServer показывает, что при десериализации создаётся соответствующая табличная переменная, которая затем заполняется примерно следующим образом (псевдокод):

```sql
insert into @tableVariable (Column1, Column2, ...)
select Column1, Column2, ...
from TableValuedFunction()
```

где `TableValuedFunction` - по-видимому, есть некая табличная функция-обёртка поверх входящего потока данных. Т.е. данные в табличную переменную поступают практически напрямую из потока данных входящего запроса, минуя языковые конструкции наподобие `insert into ... values ...`.

Comment: В случае M3 вызов Prepare был включен в измеряемый кусок кода?

Comment: А пользовательский тип, он же табличная переменная, всегда должна предварительно быть создана на стороне SQL Server или это можно как-то обойти ?

Comment: @PashaPash, да, `Prepare` был включён (я измерял полное время выполнения, т.е. каждый из M содержал открытие соединения, `truncate` целевой таблицы, затем соответствующий кусочек кода).

Comment: @iluxa1810, да, тип должен быть создан, по-моему обойти это нельзя. Вообще, если есть возможность прямой вставки, то лучше bulkcopy использовать (не будет "перекладываний" данных и необходимости в создании типа).

Comment: @i-one, можно еще попробовать с использование NO COUNT замерить скорость. По идее, в одиночных вставках будет небольшой профит, так как сервер ничего назад не возвращает.